# Does React Context/Providers inherently cause lower performance or only if it reloads a lot of components?

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a Switch component and want to pass the enabled state to the thumb component via a Provider.

For some reason I have this belief that using Providers are a heavy solution that causes performance issues, but maybe that's only when it's at the top of the app and causes a ton of components to rerender.

If I use a Provider in a switch, and say there are like 10-20 switches in a form, will that inherently cause performance issues because of all the context and providers created, or is a provider just another tool and it's fine to use if it doesn't rerender a hundred components on change?

The alternative is to require the developer using the switch to pass the enabled prop down manually to the thumb.

Is one more or less performant than the other or is this stuff negligible and I can use providers in primitive components (Switch, Button, Tooltips) and it won't effect performance much at all?

Comment: Someone else will probably be better at answering this than me, but I'll take a quick crack. When using function components there is usually no early exit out of the component tree, for example make a change at the provider level and everything below it is going to rerender until you hit a class component or React.memo where shouldComponentUpdate evaluates false. This usually isn't a problem as you aim to put high computational costs behind memoization. Now because of the possibility of the render caused by the provider change being cut short, React will now start a render from each consumer.

Comment: This usually isn't a big problem, as most components are so quick to rerender that it is insignificant, but if you were relying heavily on contexts everywhere you might see this overhead start to creep into view. There are two RFCs on the React GitHub at the moment that are discussing how they are envisioning moving forward with context and one of them will be looking at how not to trigger the extra renders when they are not needed without introducing a large overhead.

Comment: TLDR: You can overuse anything and everything. Depending on how many contexts, how large the component tree is under each consumer / provider and how complex your components are you "may" (not will) start to see some performance overhead.